# Отправка формы на почту JQuery + PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет.
Очень долгая отправка почты. Можно уже забыть что отправлял.

Уже второй день пытаюсь понять что может быть. Редирект убрал потому что вечность грузится все
А хотелось бы чтобы пользователь видел сразу страницу редиректа `Query(location).attr('href', window.location.origin + '/thanks-you-for-contacting');`

А там уже пусть само отрабатывает как нибудь

[Форма](https://easy-moving.ca/get-free-quote)

```
    (function($) {
    $(function() {
        
        jQuery('#quote_form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery('.btn ').attr('disabled','disabled');
            jQuery('#quote_form').addClass('form_sending');
            var request = {
                option       : 'com_ajax',
                module       : 'c_form',
                method       : 'sendMail',
                format       : 'row',   
                data: jQuery('#quote_form').serialize(),    
                src: window.location.href,
            };
            jQuery.ajax({
                method: 'POST', 
                data: request,
                
            })
            .success(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                //jQuery(location).attr('href', window.location.origin + '/thanks-you-for-contacting');
            });
        });
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

PHP

```
<?php 
require_once '../../configuration.php'; 
 
$jconfig = new JConfig(); 
 
$host   = $jconfig->host; 
$dbname  = $jconfig->db; 
$username  = $jconfig->user; 
$password  = $jconfig->password; 
$dbprefix  = $jconfig->dbprefix; 
 
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname); 
if (!$db) { 
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysqli_error()); 
} 
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT params FROM ' . $dbprefix .'template_styles WHERE template = "easy_moving"'); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
$params = json_decode($row['params']); 
mysqli_close($db); 
 
$to = $params->email; 
 
$subject = $_POST['subject'];  
$mailheaders = "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8rn";  
$mailheaders .= "From: SiteRobot <noreply@easy-moving.ca/>rn";  
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: [email]noreply@easy-moving.ca[/email]/";  
 
if ($subject == 'Free Quote') { 
 $message = 
 '<table> 
  <tbody> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Moving From</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movingfrom'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Moving To</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movingto'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Contact Phone</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['phone'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Full Name</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['fullname'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Email Address</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['email'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Moving Date</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movingdate'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>What Size?</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['whatsize'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>How did you hear about us?</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['howdid'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
  </tbody> 
 </table>'; 
} 
 
elseif ($subject == 'Free Estimate Online') { 
 $message = 
 '<table> 
  <tbody> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Full Name</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['fullname'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Email Address</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['email'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Contact Phone</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['phone'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Moving From</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movingfrom'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Moving To</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movingto'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Moving Date</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movingdate'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Move Size</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['movesize'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Truck Size</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['trucksize'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>Сomments</td> 
    <td>'. $_POST['comments'] .'</td> 
   </tr> 
  </tbody> 
 </table>'; 
} else { 
 die('error'); 
} 
 
$res = mail($to, $subject, $message, $mailheaders); 
echo $res; 
 
?>zz
```

[image: Настройки почты]

Comment: смотрите настройки через что настроена отправка почты через функцию `mail`. Потому что проблема не в коде как таковом. Ещё стоит посмотреть время на получение данных из БД, но не думаю что там будет долго

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. ПРикрепил настройки из самой Joomla может в них проблема?

Comment: с joomla не работал, но возможно вам стоит сменить параметр `Mailer` и настроить всё что потребуется

Comment: А через скрипт можно показать пользователю все ок, страницу что письмо полученно и тд. А дальше уже все отправки проводить?